# AnsibleAuthenticationFailure while trying to install git in the remote host

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to install git in the remote host if unavailable using the following yum module.

```
- name: Installing git if unavailable
  yum:
    name: git
    state: present
```

This fails with the "AnsibleAuthenticationFailure" error as below,

```
TASK [configure_ansible_repo : Installing git if unavailable] **********************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/centos/bhprasad/okd-ansible-installer/ansible-okd-installation/roles/configure_ansible_repo/tasks/configure_ansible_repo.yaml:21
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 130, in run
    # ensure to accumulate these
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 485, in _execute
    if self._task.evaluate_conditional(templar, variables):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 735, in _get_connection
    break
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/loader.py", line 363, in get
    pass
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/loader.py", line 339, in _load_module_source
    try:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py", line 285, in <module>
    from ansible.errors import (
ImportError: cannot import name AnsibleAuthenticationFailure

fatal: [167.xxx.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
```

Ansible Version details:

```
ansible 2.9.5
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/centos/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

OS Details of all nodes:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Comment: which OS is your remote host

Comment: All the nodes are running with Centos 7 and updated the same in the question

Comment: Could you post a verbose output? Add -vvvv flag when you're running your ansible command.

Comment: Are you able to execute other ansible modules? Are you able to install it with yum with the shell or command module, or by manually ssh'ing in and running the yum command manually? What's the ssh user? I think you might need a `become: true`, or some other become related setting in there somewhere so that the yum command can be run as root.